# Does a divorce decree automatically transfer the ownership of a car?

Tags: car, divorce

My husband and I got a divorce, and he was awarded the car. He never transferred the title or registration in his name. Am I still co-owner of the car? If he wants to sell this car with my name still on it, will he need my signature even though it was awarded to him in the divorce?

Comment: What country and state?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question only nominally related to personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

If he's willing show the divorce decree when doing the paperwork, and the other party is willing to accept this as a legal document, then no, he shouldn't need your approval or signature.

Comment: When doing what paperwork? To transfer the title? I'm sure that the DMV (or equivalent) will have to be involved.

Comment: Yes, DMV to transfer title and buyer to agree to a purchase contract.  Both need to treat the divorce decree as a legal document in order for the OP not be needed.